# draw mindmap c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to display data in a mind map view using winforms with c#

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [Nevron Diagram for .NET](http://www.nevron.com/Gallery.DiagramFor.NET.DiagramGalleryHome.aspx)